# MAX32660 SWD specifications?

Tags: swd, maxim

Where can I find the SWD (Single Wire Debug) specifications for the MAX32660? I searched the user guide and data sheet, but could not find key SWD parameters such as signal timing, which features it supports (such as packed transfers), etc.?

ARM's SWD spec says that these parameters are "implementation dependent". Should we not therefore expect to find them in the MAX32660 user guide? Or perhaps a supplemental SWD programming guide from ADI (formerly Maxim)? (Or is this information exclusively provided to a certain company that shall remain unnamed and sells $1,000 SWD programmers?)

The ARM Debug Interface v5 PDF seems to disclaim interest in documenting SWD at the electrical level:

> You can implement an ARM Serial Wire Debug interface with either a
> synchronous or an asynchronous serial connection. However, this
> chapter does not describe the physical characteristics of the SWD
> interface, such as:
>
> - asynchronous clocking, if required
> - multiple connections, if required
> - signal sampling rates.
>
> Note: Contact ARM Limited if you require more detailed information
> about the implementation of the ARM Serial Wire Debug Interface

Answer (score 0):

Signal waveforms are completely specified by ARM, apart from SWCLK rate.
Maxim/AD could have specified max SWCLK rate, but it seems they didn't.
You could probably discover this with a probe using increasing frequencies until it fails, though.

For the rest, this part uses a Cortex-M4F, which is entierely defined in ARM's [Cortex-M4 TRM (DDI0439)](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/).

If you require to dynamically discover implemented features, M4F is an implementation of ARMv7 architecture, and everything can be enumerated through registers (See [ARMv7-M ARM (DDI0403), chapter B4](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest/)).

Debug Port (DP) features depend on its version (see [ADI v5 (IHI0031)](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0031/latest/) chapter 2.2).

Mem-AP features are defined through CSW and CFG register (IHI0031, chap 7.6.3, 7.6.4).

The same goes for other Coresight components (FPB, DWT, etc). They can be enumerated through ROMTables. This is defined in [DDI0314](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0314/latest/).

Comment: Where are the waveform specs that you say ARM has published? The old PDF I have ("ARM Debug Interface v5") does not say anything about setup/hold times, or even which edge to sample on. It is missing critical details like stop bits and 0xe79e sequence. (And the new website is impossible to navigate, though you can find pieces of information if you already know of their existence)