# MAX32660 SWD: Meaning of CSYSPWRUPREQ not asserted?

Tags: arm, swd, maxim

In a working SWD sequence generated by [pyocd](https://pyocd.io/), the [MAX32660](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max32660.pdf) target's DP4 (CTRL) register has the CSYSPWRUPREQ bit set, as follows (as reported by the probe's console):

```
07535805 main.c:97      Got UDP, len=5
07535807 main.c:109       Connection from remote port 55000
07535811 main.c:125       SWD Connect
07535813 SWD.c:102          SWD Connection sequence
07538852 main.c:137       SWD READ  IDCODE (DP0)
07538918 SWD.c:199          data[0] <= 0x2ba01477 <= pins
07538928 main.c:182       Sending response, payload length = 6
07541311 main.c:96
07541313 main.c:97      Got UDP, len=27
07541316 main.c:119       SN Match (1)
07541319 main.c:148       SWD WRITE ABORT (DP0)
07541322 SWD.c:226          data[0] => 0x0000001e => pins
07541425 main.c:148       SWD WRITE SELECT (DP8)
07541428 SWD.c:226          data[0] => 0x00000000 => pins
07541524 main.c:148       SWD WRITE CTRL (DP4)
07541527 SWD.c:226          data[0] => 0x50000000 => pins
07541630 main.c:137       SWD READ  CTRL (DP4)
07541695 SWD.c:199          data[0] <= 0xf0000040 <= pins  <= CSYSPWRUPREQ asserted
07541701 main.c:182       Sending response, payload length = 6
```

However, I can also reliably induce a state of the MAX32660 where CSYSPWRUPREQ is NOT asserted:

```
563963783 main.c:100     Got UDP, len=5
563963786 main.c:111       Connection from remote port 55000
563963789 main.c:127       SWD Connect
563963790 SWD.c:104          SWD Connection sequence
563970040 main.c:140       SWD READ  IDCODE (DP0)
563970253 SWD.c:204          data[0] <= 0x2ba01477 <= pins
563970269 main.c:185       Sending response, payload length = 6
564016266 main.c:99
564016267 main.c:100     Got UDP, len=27
564016270 main.c:121       SN Match (1)
564016273 main.c:151       SWD WRITE ABORT (DP0)
564016277 SWD.c:232          data[0] => 0x0000001e => pins
564016616 main.c:151       SWD WRITE SELECT (DP8)
564016619 SWD.c:232          data[0] => 0x00000000 => pins
564016958 main.c:151       SWD WRITE CTRL (DP4)
564016961 SWD.c:232          data[0] => 0x50000000 => pins
564017299 main.c:140       SWD READ  CTRL (DP4)
564017512 SWD.c:204          data[0] <= 0x00000040 <= pins  <= CSYSPWRUPREQ NOT asserted
564017528 main.c:185       Sending response, payload length = 6
564018088 main.c:99
564018090 main.c:100     Got UDP, len=6
564018092 main.c:121       SN Match (2)
564018096 main.c:140       SWD READ  CTRL (DP4)
564018308 SWD.c:204          data[0] <= 0x00000040 <= pins  <= CSYSPWRUPREQ NOT asserted
564018325 main.c:185       Sending response, payload length = 6
564019098 main.c:99
564019100 main.c:100     Got UDP, len=6
564019103 main.c:121       SN Match (3)
564019105 main.c:140       SWD READ  CTRL (DP4)
564019319 SWD.c:204          data[0] <= 0x00000040 <= pins  <= CSYSPWRUPREQ NOT asserted
564019334 main.c:185       Sending response, payload length = 6
```

What can cause this condition?

(To trigger it, I just have GPIO activity in the target. It's not related to the time between the SWD reset sequence and the read of CTRL. The SWD signals look clean on the scope. The difference between the two cases is 0xf0000040 vs 0x00000040, which is exactly the 4 PWRUP bits, so it seems very likely that I am reading the correct register. The probe is fully functional when the target GPIO activity is turned off).

The ARM documentation doesn't make sense. It says this bit is asserted after power-on reset. The device has been powered on for several minutes. Therefore the bit should always be set?

Comment: What is a "working SWD sequence"?

Comment: @Rodo A sequence of SWD reads or writes, for example generated by `pyocd`, that succeeds in (for example) programming the target.